# ASP extracting table on HTML

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript

I have an HTML structure saved on an ASP variable called strResponse1

all i want to do is to extract a specific table on it. the table has its constant class named "dataTableParent". I had made a simple code that extract the table using Ubound and Lbound VBScript Function

```
Here is my simple code: 

Dim str, tmp, toptmp, bottmp, tablestr
str = strResponse1
tmp = split(str, "dataTableParent")
            toptmp = tmp(UBound(tmp))
            tmp2 = split(toptmp, "</table>")
            bottmp = tmp2(LBound(tmp2))
            tablestr = "<table class=" & chr(34) & "dataTableParent" & bottmp & "</table>"
```

So I used ASP Trim function, Ubound for trimming the Upper Bound string, and LBound for trimming the Lower Bound string. I used the table class: `dataTableParent` to get the starting point for upper bound trimming and `</table>` to get the ending point for lower bound trimiming. The code is working perfectly on extracting the table but the PROBLEM is, sometimes there is another table on the parent "`<TD>`" that struggling me to extract the the table correctly.

Check this HTML sample for table structure

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <table class="dataTableParent">
       <tr>
             <td>
                   <table>
                        <tr>
                              <td>This is an example of another table elements</td>
                        </tr>
                   </table>
             </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Since my code identifies only the first closing table tag, the trimming stops when it found the first closing tag `</table>`, knowing that there are two closing tag for table here. So how can i possibly extract the table on its correct ending tag? Anyone could help? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always: Don't use string processing on HTML.

```
Option Explicit

Dim doc, table
Set doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")

' ... set strResponse1 ...

doc.write strResponse1

For Each table In doc.body.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    If table.className = "dataTableParent" Then
        ' use DOM methods to navigate to correct table cell and extract data 
        ' with the help of, e.g., innerText()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: how about extracting the table itself? is it possible?

Comment: like i'm just ignoring other html elements and retaining only the table that i want `"dataTableParent"` is it possible to extract this table only?

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "extract". If you want the table's HTML as a string, then `table.outerHTML` would do it. If you want data from particular table cells I'd advise to continue to work with the DOM instead of pulling out the HTML string.

Comment: well all i want is to extract the particular table on the HTML and putting the extracted table into string.

Comment: but the problem is, sometimes there are another table inside the `<TD>` so like for example shown above.. if i will to trim them down using this table classs: dataTableParent as its starting identifier and the closing tag `</table>` as its closing identifier, it will rip only data from the table identified until its found the first closing tag </table>... 

So how can I be able to find the correct closing tag so i can extract the table correctly?

Comment: You are not listening to what I say. You must not use string processing on HTML. There are no "closing identifiers". There are no flat strings that you can use for search and replace. Use the DOM methods to navigate and manipulate the document tree. You can search for elements, remove them, extact or change their contents, all without using a single string function. String processing is not what you are looking for.

Comment: ok..i just dont know how to start things up.. i'm not really familiar using DOM but im reading it at w3schools for more information. If you could give me atleast one example how to navigate the table using DOM, it will be a very useful one for starters like me.

Comment: Thank you for the bright ideas you gave me @Tomalak. I have created a new codes using outerHTML anyway. it worked.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice, glad to hear that you got it working. :) Try to revisit your code and turn it into a DOM-based solution at some point, you will be a lot better off, I promise. I suggest the following: Use the VBA IDE in any MS Office program to write and debug VBS code. You'll get syntax highlighting, code completion, an interactive debugger, breakpoints, variable inspection at runtime etc for free. And at the end you can copy working code to your ASP page.

Comment: There are a lot of DOM properties and method i have read yesterday.. i used GetElementsbyTagName to get the whole table in html and I've used If Else condition statement to filter the table using className properties. Those code works perfectly fine. What about getting the table using the table ID?

Comment: i tried getting the table thru its ID this time using getAttribute and getAttributeNode but to no avail. what is the best DOM properties to use on it?

Comment: I got it, i used: 

Set table = HTMLDoc.getElementById("results-table")
tablestr = table.outerHTML